# Getting java IO Exception Sometimes while accessing Hive using Hortonworks ODBC Driver in c#

Tags: c#, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

1. I am able to connect to My Hive using Hortonworks hive odbc driver. We are using ODBC connection we have ODBC connection string in our configuration.
2. while executing query sometimes we are getting 'Message: ERROR [HY000] [Hortonworks][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem'
3. I googled and found we can use 'hive.fetch.task.conversion=none' for resolving this we tried this still we are facing same problem.
4. We are using Hive 0.14

Comment: I am new to HIve, Is there any other driver for connecting to Hive (Data lake) which is performance effective?

Answer (score 0):

1. Finally Found the issue, the property that i was using incorrect "hive.fetch.task.conversion=none" (This can be used in Jdbc connection)
2. For Horton Works ODBC driver we have to use "ssp_hive.fetch.task.conversion=none" in connection string
3. I created DSN and used it in SSIS project to get the connection string for ODBC

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I also saw this exact error when trying to use beeline on Hive 1.2.1.

`SET hive.fetch.task.conversion = none;`

This did solve it on beeline.

Comment: thanks Cory i found the solution i was aware of this property, it was working in Jdbc and not in odbc we need to apply diff property for Horton works odbc connection string "ssp_hive.fetch.task.conversion=none"